# Read() blocking problem

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm developing a server application in C#. Clients can connect to the server and make various requests. Currently, when a client connects I spawn a new thread to handle the request(s). I'm using the TCPClient class to handle client connections. My server works as follows:

1. Client connect to server with a request
2. Server handles request
3. Server waits to see if client has any more requests
4. If client does not make another request within some timeout period, the server kills the connection

My problem is the following:

When I read from the NetworkStream object that I get from the TCPClient class, the NetworkStream Read() method does not block if there is no Data Available. When the server reaches step #3, I would like to set some timeout on the NetworkStream and if the client does not make any more requests within that duration the server should kill the connection when that timeout exception is thrown. When my server reaches step 3, the NetworkStream Read() method does not block, reguardless of what I set it's ReadTimeout property to be. Can anyone help me out, or suggest a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: Could you use UDP instead and make it connectionless?

Answer (score 2):

NetworkStream.Read and ReadByte should block until the timeout if there's no data to read.  I think it's far more likely that the call is reading something, probably a bunch of zeroes.  Check the data being sent by the client carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You should graduate from using Read() to the [BeginRead()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx) method and look into parallel processing. Network programming is not for the faint of heart.

Basically you don't want to create a loop polling for data.

```
while(!timedout && !stream.DataAvailable) sleep(0); // This is bad.
if(steam.DataAvailable) steam.Read();
```

Instead it makes more sense to do something like this. Create a reset event, call BeginRead(), and release the reset event on the callback. Something like the following:

```
void clientThread()
{
   stream.BeginRead(myCallback);
   resetEvent.WaitOne(timeout)
}
void myCallback
{
   resetEvent.Set();
}
```

Comment: He already is spawning a new thread per client, in which case using BeginRead makes less sense....

Comment: It makes more sense than using sleep. http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx

Comment: Spencer: I edited my answer to adjust using a waithandle, but in this case, I don't necessarily believe sleep is a bad thing - it really depends on whether or not the amount of time slept is critical (since Richie's main argument is that SleepEx provides no timeout or guarantee that you'll return in the time you request).

Comment: And it still makes less sense than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the NetworkStream in a BufferedStream. BufferedStream.Read will block until at least 1 byte is available.

Comment: It seems that I can't set a timeout duration on a BufferedStream wrapped around a NetworkStream (System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream...) So, I would still have to handle the timeout manually if I went this route

Comment: Setup timers to handle the timeouts. when the timer closes the socket an exception will be thrown on the read method. Then when data is read, reset the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout.aspx

Looks like you get the NetworkStream from the TcpClient using GetStream(), then call the Read() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly force the NetworkStream to block when there is no available data:

```
TcpClient clientConnection = new TcpClient();

if(clientConnection.Available > 0)
{ 
  //You want to continue execution even though there is no available data to be read from the server then:
  clientConnection.Client.Blocking = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to handle the "timeout" yourself, since NetworkStream.Read() doesn't provide a way to do that.

What you'll probably want to do in your client thread is use some combination of NetworkStream.DataAvailable and/or NetworkStream.CanRead in conjunction with a blocking/timeout mechanism (such as using a WaitHandle.WaitOne call with a timeout) to provide the client with time to make data available.  If nothing comes in after a specified time, just shutdown the connection, and exit.

Comment: Ahem. http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx

Comment: I don't always agree with Peter Richie's arguments in there, particularly in user constructed threads.  He even (in the discussion) advocates using Thread.Sleep(1) in some cases.  That being said, in this case, I think using a WaitHandle is probably a better design, so I changed my answer.

Comment: If the client thread is waiting for data but only using the Read() method it will need to be looping until data is available. If you don't use Sleep() with Read() that's even worse.

Comment: Yes - I was suggesting a loop with a blocking mechanism of some form.

Comment: And what releases the block? Another thread polling the client stream for data? How is that a better idea than BeginRead()?

Comment: WaitHandle.WaitOne allows a timeout to be specified.  THis was actually Peter Richie's suggestion to many people to avoid sleep in operations like this...

Comment: That's no better if there's nothing to release the handle. See my answer.